# How to close the current form in a SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls, splitcontainer

I have a user control in my SplitContainer's right panel. A form opens below the user control. Now if i click a button in the user control, that current form should close and a new form should open. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement below logic in your app easily:

```
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Remove(myPanel);
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(myOtherPanel);
```

which will remove the existing panel from the container and place the other panel. You can extend the same logic to place forms, or separate controls on the container easily.